# Trouble with $routeProvider in page served by Express.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to build my first Express.js/Angular application but am having trouble with `$routeProvider` on the page being served by the Express.js application. Here is the `server.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/views/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("I'm listening");
});
```

The `index.html` page renders and includes the following Angular code:

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/main', {
                templateUrl:'/client/views/main.html'
            });
    });
```

Yet when navigating to `localhost:3000/#/main`, nothing is injected into the `<ng-view>`

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check your console for erros?

Comment: Your express app doesn't seem to handle serving /client/views/main.html check out express-static middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having encountered this issue before I found a solution by telling express to serve files statically.

```
app.use(express.static('client'));
```

This tells express to send files from the 'client' directory as-is. This is used for files such as images, CSS & client side JavaScript. When referencing a file statically, paths are relative to the specified static directory so `/client/views/main.html` would be `/views/main.html`.

You can view the documentation for the express static middle ware [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Comment: So would I still be serving the `index.html` from my `server.js` file?